# 2 ways of running application. Is this the same?

Tags: c#, winforms

This is a very simple question. I want to know if this:

```
new Form1().Show();
Application.Run();
```

Is the same that this:

```
Application.Run(new Form1());
```

It seems to work the same, but maybe something change and I'm not taking notice.
The reason why I'm asking this is because I'm trying to implement MVP pattern in WinForms application, and if it's the same, I have some methods that I don't need anymore.

Sorry for bad english.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157902(v=vs.110).aspx), there is a subtle difference:

```
public static void Run(Form mainForm)
```

> This method adds an event handler to the mainForm parameter for the Closed event. The event handler calls ExitThread to clean up the application.

So it seems the latter method is better, if you want the application to clean up after itself when the form is closed.